# Saving additional field from dropdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I m having list of relations, when I select `Other`,  new fields shows `AddOther`, and when I enter `Test` into new field, in database i get stored `Other`, because it takes from the `f.select`. What should i do to save into database from new field when i choose `Other` from the list.

```
= f.select(:relationship, ['Father', 'Mother', "Sibling", "Children", "Friend", "Spouse", "Other"], {}, { :class => 'form-select  RelationshipSelect'  })
        fieldset class="form-group" style="display:none"
        input#AddOther.mt-4.form-control[type="text" style="display:none" placeholder="Enter other relationship"]

$('.RelationshipSelect').change(function() {
    var v;
    v = $(this).val();
    if (v == 'Other') {
        $('#AddOther').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('#AddOther').slideUp();
    }
});
```

I tried to add `AddOther` to f.select but no progress.
Cant figure it out how to save `AddOther` into list to be able to save it as `Father`, `Mother`....

Comment: try naming the "AddOther" field to "model_name[relationship]", it will overwrite the "relationship" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels risky, because the relationship will only be valid/available for one use.  You will be prone to pick up lots of "dirty" data.

That said, you could add jquery to monitor the 'change' event of AddOther, which would retrieve the value, add a new option to the select, set the value of the select to that value.

```
$('#AddOther').on('change', function(){
  relationship = $(this).val();
  $('.RelationshipSelect').append("<option value=\"" + relationship + "\">" + relationship + "</option>").val(relationship);
  $(this).slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way was to create another column and save data from additional field in that column, and displayed it like that.